# Rack gem in not getting unpacked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my server is having rack gems as:

> rack (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)

when i run the following command in my project/vendor/gems folder:

> gem unpack rack-1.0.0

It shows the following error message:

> Error: Gem 'rack-1.0.0' not installed.

Any idea on this??

Thanks,

Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gem unpack rack -v=1.0.0
```

The gem `rack-1.0.0` does not exist because `1.0.0` is not part of the gem name.